# How to rewrite URLs except for an action using namespaces in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, namespaces

I am running Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to set up my routes in order to rewrite URLs using namespaces, except for an action (the *index* action).

In the routes.rb file I have:

```
namespace "users", :path => "user" do
  resources :accounts
end
```

So, for example, URLs to "show"/"create new" accounts are:

```
http://<site_name>/user/accounts/1
http://<site_name>/user/accounts/new
```

I would like to rewrite/redirect those URLs, *except* for the 'index' action, as/to

```
# For the 'index' action I would like to use plural 'users' instead of 'user'
http://<site_name>/users/accounts
# and
http://<site_name>/users
```

**How to do that?**

---

I tryed this

```
namespace "users", :path => "user", :except => :index do
  resources :accounts
end
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
namespace "users", :path => "user" do
  resources :accounts, :except => :index
end
```